# Custom List - Date limit for new item

Tags: 2010, custom-list

I am looking for some help around customizing a list from SharePoint front end as I do not have access to a SharePoint developer.

We have a Nomination Form for Awards (custom list). The Awards forms are supposed to be submitted before 10th of every month.  After which, the users should not be able to add new items in this list. I need help from you all on how do I get this done!

One way is to manually change access rights for everyone from Contribute to Read, but this is rather risky option - user groups painfully created for 5000 users may be  get accidently deleted.

Comment: Do you create a new list for every month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a validation for the list:

1. Go to List -> List Settings -> Validation settings
2. As formular enter `=DAY(Created)<10`
3. As user message enter `Entries must be added before the 10th`

Comment: Thank you very much Per. this is a great solution and it works. :)

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to customize this now to allow dates from 27th till 10th of every month? Something like this would work? '=DAY(Created)>27<10'

Comment: It should be something like `=OR(DAY(Created)>27, DAY(Created)<10)` see [Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)

Comment: Awesome! this one works! :) I tried changing the date to today's date and it allowed me to submit, but after changing it to 22, it does not. Thanks a Ton Per! :) :)

Comment: Hi @Per, I am facing an issue after I have set up this validation. Items once created, the list is not allowing them to be edited, while giving out the same validation error message we have set up for the date validation.

Comment: You should be able to set the validation to `=AND(OR(DAY(Created)>27, DAY(Created)<10),OR(DAY(Modified)>27, DAY(Modified)<10))`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @Per! This did not solve my concern actually. I am still getting the same validation error. I know am being a pita here, but could you help me with another solution here?

Comment: Sorry for last wrong comment. It seems you need to have the formular as `=OR(OR(DAY(Created)>27, DAY(Created)<10),Created<Modified)`. Not really sure why you need that last part to be able to modify:-(